# Most practical virtualisation setup for one colocated server?

Tags: debian, virtualization, xen

I have an own server which I'd like to (ab)use virtual servers on. It's intended to be kind of a laboratory for me in which I can try things out without ruining the system. The criterias I am searching for here is easy-to-use deployment tools along with easy "start-stop" things.

Which virtualization tools/systems/setups are usable for this type of things? Is Xen cloud platform a good use for this? Are there like web-ui's for a basic Xen-setup? Currently I'm running debian lenny on it and if possible, I'll stick with it.

I'd like it to be free as in beer/speech as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the tool you have to try first is virtualbox. I wouldn't use that in production for the moment (this may change in the future), but for development/testing, this would be great.